# how to redirect rewrite rule link using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How  do I create rewrite rule to get pretty link using `.htaccess`. for example I have a link like this:

`http://localhost/piratefiles/view.php?idp=2&cat=Animation&pst=In-this-Corner-of-the-World-(Kono-Sekai-no-Katasumi-ni)/`

I want to make my url like this, I do'nt want `(` or `)` or `:` etc in my link.

`http://localhost/piratefiles/view/2/in-this-corner-of-the-world-kono-sekai-no-katsumi-ni`

or just

`http://localhost/piratefiles/view/2/`

my code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^([^/]*?)(?:/|%20)+([^/]+?(?:/|%20)+.*)$"
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1-%2 [N,NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^([^/]*?)(?:/|%20)+([^/]+?)/?$"
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1-%2/ [L,R=302,NE]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/$    index.php    [L]

#Your section
RewriteRule ^view/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    view.php?idp=$1&cat=$2&pst=$3   [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.akshadainfosystem.com/

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Put this code in your .htaccess file and clear all cookie

Comment: not redirect automatic, i need to create manual path for it. is there no way to redirect automatic?